# How to insert NULL values from Spark into Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I'm using the `spark-csv` to create a file that I then use in a `COPY` command to load the data into `Redshift`. According to the `Redshift` documentation, a valid literal for a `NULL` value should be `NULL` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Boolean_type.html.

However, I can't get Redshift to recognize this, what is the correct literal value to set for `NULL` values so Redshift will correctly recognize it on a `COPY` command from `S3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the value in your `COPY` statement with `NULL AS 'NULL'` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-null-as

I would suggest trying out the `spark-reshift` library for loading Redshift. It takes care of a lot of these issues for you. https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not help for `COPY` command but I also faced similar `NULL` value issue. My `Dataset<Row>` was having null values, which I need to load into Redshift table. Redshift treated null values in `Dataset<Row>` as 'null' string values. My load failed if the column size is varchar(2) as null as a string is having 4 characters.

There is an option available for write method i.e. `option("nullValue","")` which helped me to convert NULL into a blank string value.

```
finalDS.write().format("jdbc")
        .option("url", url)                        
        .option("dbtable", dbTable)
        .option("user", dbUser)
        .option("password", dbPassword)
        .option("nullString","")
        .option("nullInt","")
        .option("tempdir", "s3a://bucket-name/tmp")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .save();
```